# Crash on collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having 2 structs. The data from these are added to an array called `productData1`. This array has images as well as some details like `name`, `rate` etc. The images and the data `name`, `rate` etc.are to be displayed in a collection view. In the `collectionview cellForItemAt...` this is how I'm showing the data..

```
let productObject = productData1[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = productObject.name
cell.rateLabel.text = productObject.theRate
```

This is working fine. And the images I'm trying to show like so...

```
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: productObject.images[0].url) {// Crashed here..
            let img = UIImage(data: data)
            self.arrayOfURLImages.append(img!)
            cell.recipeImageView.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
        }
```

But when I try to display the images like this, the images do get displayed in the `collectionview`. But when I scroll them, I get a crash in this line `if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: productObject....` saying `fatal error: Index out of range`. Hope somebody can help...

**EDIT** This is the full code in `cellForItemAt...`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell

    let productObject = productData1[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = productObject.name
    cell.rateLabel.text = productObject.theRate

        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: productObject.images[0].url) {
            let img = UIImage(data: data)
            print(img!)
            self.arrayOfURLImages.append(img!)

            cell.recipeImageView.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
        }

    cell.sellButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(SellBtnTapped(_:)),for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
```

}

Comment: your arrayOfURLImages array  has one value (which is at index 0) and if you will have collection view with 10 rows, so yes it's a crash.

Comment: I did try with `indexpath.item`& `indexpath.row` instead of `[0]`. But doing so crashes it right away even without once displaying the images...

Comment: show more code where are you calling this ?

Comment: you mean the entire `cellForRowAt` code...?

Comment: yes show code for collection view if possible.In short detail code for above.

Comment: Have added the entire code in `cellForItemAt...`

Comment: try productObject.images[indexPath.item].url and also check you have productObject.count in numberOfRows method.And you should also look for code "How to display images from server url?" this way is not correct.

Comment: I did try this..`productObject.images[indexPath.item].url ` and the count is also there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157776/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-bws).